# List inside list for nested RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am stuck in one loop condition, I am using for loop inside another for loop for displaying data in nested recyclerview which I am fetching from Json response but I am not getting required solution, below is my code, I am also attaching my resulted output and also attaching required output, if anyone know the solution then please help me.

My code is here

```
 JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.getJSONArray("data");

 for(int i=0;i < jsonArray.length();i++){

       JSONObject object1  =jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
       JSONArray jsonArrayRates = object1.getJSONArray("rates");
       Log.e("jsonArraySize",String.valueOf(jsonArrayRates.length()));
       String fuel_type = null;

       demoCarSectionList.clear();

       for (int j=0;j < jsonArrayRates.length();j++){
           JSONObject objectRates=jsonArrayRates.getJSONObject(j);                                
           access_Rate=objectRates.getString("access_rate");
           String carID=objectRates.getString("car_id");
           Log.e( "carIdInside" ,carID);
           amount= (rate_int * time_int);
           freeDriving= String.valueOf(distance_Car);
           demoCarSectionList.add(access_Rate);
       }

       Log.e( "value_inside" , demoCarSectionList.get(1));
       demoCarList.add((ArrayList<String>) demoCarSectionList);

 }




    Resulted output from above code-
    E/RateList: [12, 11.5, 11]
    E/carList: [[12, 11.5, 11]]
    E/RateList: [14, 10, 15]
    E/carList: [[14, 10, 15], [14, 10, 15]]
    E/RateList: [14, 13, 12]
    E/carList: [[14, 13, 12], [14, 13, 12], [14, 13, 12]]
    E/RateList: [14, 18, 19]
    E/carList: [[14, 18, 19], [14, 18, 19], [14, 18, 19], [14, 18, 19]]
    E/RateList: [15, 19, 10]
    E/carList: [[15, 19, 10], [15, 19, 10], [15, 19, 10], [15, 19, 10], 
    [15, 19, 10]]
    E/RateList: [14, 16, 12]
    E/carList: [[14, 16, 12], [14, 16, 12], [14, 16, 12], [14, 16, 12], 
    [14, 16, 12], [14, 16, 12]]
    E/RateList: [14, 13, 12]
    E/carList: [[14, 13, 12], [14, 13, 12], [14, 13, 12], [14, 13, 12], 
    [14, 13, 12], [14, 13, 12], [14, 13, 12]]
    E/RateList: [15, 14, 13]
    E/carList: [[15, 14, 13], [15, 14, 13], [15, 14, 13], [15, 14, 13], 
    [15, 14, 13], [15, 14, 13], [15, 14, 13], [15, 14, 13]]
    E/RateList: [13, 12, 11]
    E/carList: [[13, 12, 11], [13, 12, 11], [13, 12, 11], [13, 12, 11], 
    [13, 12, 11], [13, 12, 11], [13, 12, 11], [13, 12, 11], [13, 12, 11]]
    E/RateList: [14, 13, 12]
    E/carList: [[14, 13, 12], [14, 13, 12], [14, 13, 12], [14, 13, 12], 
    [14, 13, 12], [14, 13, 12], [14, 13, 12], [14, 13, 12], [14, 13, 12], 
    [14, 13, 12]]
    E/RateList: [13, 12, 10]
    E/carList: [[13, 12, 10], [13, 12, 10], [13, 12, 10], [13, 12, 10], 
    [13, 12, 10], [13, 12, 10], [13, 12, 10], [13, 12, 10], [13, 12, 10], 
    [13, 12, 10], [13, 12, 10]]



   Required output-
   E/RateList: [12, 11.5, 11]
   E/carList: [[12, 11.5, 11]]
   E/RateList: [14, 10, 15]
   E/carList: [[12, 11.5, 11], [14, 10, 15]]
   E/RateList: [14, 13, 12]
   E/carList: [[12, 11.5, 11], [14, 10, 15], [14, 13, 12]]
   E/RateList: [14, 18, 19]
   E/carList: [[12, 11.5, 11], [14, 10, 15], [14, 13, 12], [14, 18, 19]]
   E/RateList: [15, 19, 10]
   E/carList: [[12, 11.5, 11], [14, 10, 15], [14, 13, 12], [14, 18, 19], 
   [15, 19, 10]]
   E/RateList: [14, 16, 12]
   E/carList: [[12, 11.5, 11], [14, 10, 15], [14, 13, 12], [14, 18, 19], 
   [15, 19, 10], [14, 16, 12]]
   E/RateList: [14, 13, 12]
   E/carList: [[12, 11.5, 11], [14, 10, 15], [14, 13, 12], [14, 18, 19], 
   [15, 19, 10], [14, 16, 12], [14, 13, 12]]
   E/RateList: [15, 14, 13]
   E/carList: [[12, 11.5, 11], [14, 10, 15], [14, 13, 12], [14, 18, 19], 
   [15, 19, 10], [14, 16, 12], [14, 13, 12], [15, 14, 13]]
   E/RateList: [13, 12, 11]
   E/carList: [[12, 11.5, 11], [14, 10, 15], [14, 13, 12], [14, 18, 19], 
   [15, 19, 10], [14, 16, 12], [14, 13, 12], [15, 14, 13], [13, 12, 11]]
   E/RateList: [14, 13, 12]
   E/carList: [[12, 11.5, 11], [14, 10, 15], [14, 13, 12], [14, 18, 19], 
   [15, 19, 10], [14, 16, 12], [14, 13, 12], [15, 14, 13], [13, 12, 11], 
   [14, 13, 12]]
   E/RateList: [13, 12, 10]
   E/carList: [[12, 11.5, 11], [14, 10, 15], [14, 13, 12], [14, 18, 19], 
   [15, 19, 10], [14, 16, 12], [14, 13, 12], [15, 14, 13], [13, 12, 11], 
   [14, 13, 12], [13, 12, 10]]
```

Answer (score 0):

after struggling for 2-3 days i got the answer, it all about initialization of list, its very small mistake, demoCarSectionList need to initialize locally so it will update the list for every index of loop.

The code should be like this

```
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.getJSONArray("data");

    for(int i=0;i < jsonArray.length();i++){

   JSONObject object1  =jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
   JSONArray jsonArrayRates = object1.getJSONArray("rates");
   Log.e("jsonArraySize",String.valueOf(jsonArrayRates.length()));
   String fuel_type = null;

   demoCarSectionList= new ArrayList<>();
   demoCarSectionList.clear();

   for (int j=0;j < jsonArrayRates.length();j++){
       JSONObject objectRates=jsonArrayRates.getJSONObject(j);                                
       access_Rate=objectRates.getString("access_rate");
       String carID=objectRates.getString("car_id");
       Log.e( "carIdInside" ,carID);
       amount= (rate_int * time_int);
       freeDriving= String.valueOf(distance_Car);
       demoCarSectionList.add(access_Rate);
   }

   Log.e( "value_inside" , demoCarSectionList.get(1));
   demoCarList.add((ArrayList<String>) demoCarSectionList);
```

}